# Change the marker position by onClick google map ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I'm using a google map in iPhone app by objective-c, it is ok and the marker is in a given location. I want when click on a specific location change the marker location to the selected location by clicking the map.
How to do this?
Thanks in advance.

my code:

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:29.964996
                                                        longitude:30.939680 zoom:5
                                                          bearing:0
                                                     viewingAngle:0
                             ];
_mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:viewOfMap.bounds camera:camera];
_mapView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;


[_mapView addObserver:self
           forKeyPath:@"myLocation"
              options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
              context:NULL];

[viewOfMap addSubview:_mapView];


dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //_mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    _mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
});

GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lag);
marker.map = _mapView;
```

Comment: Check this SO question [28955976](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28955976/gmsmarker-icon-from-center-ios) and [16686795](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16686795/ios-google-maps-sdk-gmsmarker-positioning) if it can help you ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker
{
     marker.icon=[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedicon.png"];//selected marker

     for (int i=0; i<[markerArray count]; i++) 
     {
         GMSMarker *unselectedMarker=markerArray[i];
         //check selected marker and unselected marker position
         if(unselectedMarker.position.latitude!=marker.position.latitude &&    unselectedMarker.position.longitude!=marker.position.longitude)
         {
             unselectedMarker.icon=[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselectedicon.png"];
         } 
     }
     return NO;
}
```

Comment: good, its working fine, this code is used, if you want to change the marker image on click event.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to tap a location and have a marker move to that location.

Be sure that your view controller implements `GMSMapViewDelegate`and use the `didTapAtCoordinate` delegate method. Something like this:

```
-(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
    [marker setPosition:coordinate];
}
```